# std::forward infinite recursion size effect

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
class Test
{
  public:
    Test()
    {
    }

    Test(const Test &other) noexcept
    {
        *this = other;
    }

    Test(Test &&other) noexcept
    {
        *this = std::move(other);
    }

    auto operator = (const Test &other) noexcept -> Test&
    {
        // Make a copy of "other"
        // ...
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator = (Test &&other) noexcept -> Test&
    {
        // Move "other"
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I would like group together move and copy constructors. From what I understood It can be achieved using std::forward like this:

```
template <class T>
Test(T &&other) noexcept
{
    *this = std::forward<T>(other);
}
```

It looks to be working well if used carefully as follows:

```
Test test;
Test test1 { test };
Test test2 { std::move(test) };
```

On the other hand it creates an infinite recursion if I try to instantiate a Test object with a value of type different than Test:

```
Test test { 1 }; // Creates an infinite recursion
```

Is there a way to restrict the instantiation of the Test object with the (r||l)values of type Test only?

Comment: [OT] implementing a copy constructor in terms of assignment will fail as soon as any of the class' members is not default-constructible, not to mention it's pointless to default-construct members first and then assign a new value to each

Comment: Define "creates an infinite recursion". What _actual_ behaviour do you see?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just a guess, but the rhs of the assignment will probably implicit-construct a temporary from the non-`Test` value or rvalue using the very constructor being implemented to do so.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I guess so too, but this is a Question & Answer site, not a Guess & Answer site, so the OP shall define their problem scientifically.

Comment: Defining assignment in terms of a copy construction is sometimes useful, but the other way around is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @PiotrS. Good point about "not default-constructible". The purpose was to share the code between copy constructor and copy assignment.

Comment: @AlexandreA. the idiomatic way to do that is to define a correct copy constructor, and define a correct `Test::swap(Test&) noexcept` function, and then it's very easy to define the assignment operator using the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, it was a good read.

Answer (score 5):

The infinite recursion is caused by an instance of `Test` being constructed in the assignment operation, which involves calling the constructor again. The reason is that you do not have assignment operators defined for anything other than a `Test`.

More precisely, read this:

```
template<typename T>
Test(T &&other)
{
    *this = forward<T>(other);
}
```

as this:

```
template<typename T>
Test(T &&other)
{
    this->operator = (Test{forward<T>(other)}); // <- Recursion here
}
```

for any `T` that is not a `Test`.

To resolve the problem, you would need to define an appropriately constrained assignment operator, like so:

```
template<typename T>
auto operator = (T &&value)
-> typename std::enable_if<
    ! std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, Test>::value,
    Test &
    >::type
{
    // Assignment involving a T that is not a Test
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Although this solves the infinite recursion and is technically correct (so upvoted), defining copy construction in terms of assignment is still a bad design and this fix shouldn't be used, instead the design should be changed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I would have suggested defining everything through constructors, though that would have required a much longer answer. This was more of a "fish" as opposed to "fishing lessons."